# AFNetworking post image in nested json

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I have to send a nested json request which includes an image in an inner hierarchy. eg:

```
{"product" : {
  "catalogue_id" : "x", 
   "name" : "my product", 
   "image" : #<image>
  } 
}
```

Problem is if I try using `multipartFormRequestWithMethod:path:parameters:constructingBodyWithBlock:` (and `appendPartWithFileData:name:fileName:mimeType:`), passing in catalogue_id and name as params, the image field is appended after "product", like so:

```
{"product" : {
  "catalogue_id" : "x", 
   "name" : "my product"
  } ,
   "image" : #<image>
}
```

Is there a way to specify that the image field is nested at certain depth?

Thanks heaps

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found the answer with some tinkering: `product[image]` in the name did the trick

Sample code:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[client sharedInstance]
                         multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" 
                                                   path:@"/catalogues/1/products.json" 
                                             parameters:params
                              constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
                                  [formData appendPartWithFileData:img
                                                              name:@"product[image]" 
                                                          fileName:@"myimage.jpg" 
                                                          mimeType:@"image/jpg"];
                                  }];
```

Comment: seeing product[image] just helped me greatly! thanks for coming back to answer your own question!