# AFNetworking post image in nested json in array of dictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

How to send a nested json request which includes an image in an array of dictionary ex:

```
    @{"Contact" : @[@{
                "id" : "x1",
                "name" : "my product1",
                "image" : #<image1>
               },
               {
                "id" : "x2",
                "name" : "my product2", 
                "image" : #<image2>
              }] 
            };
```

We are taking reference from this link 
[AFNetworking post image in nested json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11087678/afnetworking-post-image-in-nested-json)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  NSData *imgData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(anImage);
  NSString *newStr = [anImageName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/"
                                                          withString:@"_"];



  [request addData:imgData
   withFileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",newStr]
   andContentType:@"image/png"
   forKey:anOtherKey];
```

I digged into AFNetworking documentation and found they appending the image in an NSMutableRequest like this:

```
  AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];
  NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"avatar.jpg"], 0.5);
  NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"/upload" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData) {
 [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"avatar" fileName:@"avatar.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
 }];
```

Comment: Hi …. Thanks for reply.

Here, we are passing contacts[image] to indicate that we have dictionary inside another dictionary like 

{"Contact" : @{
                "id" : "x1", "image" : #<image1>
               } }
 
[formData appendPartWithFileData:pictureData
                                    name:@"contacts[image]"
                                fileName:@"image" mimeType:@"image/png"];

But we are having an array of dictionaries like

@{"Contact" : @[@{
                "id" : "x1","image" : #<image1>
               }] }; 
Now what we have to pass in place of contacts[image] ?