# How can I upload image with JSON parameters with Alamofire in Swift?

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

I need to upload an image to the server endpoint where the structure has to be as following:

```
    {
        "name": "",
        "description": "",
        "photo": imageFile
    }
```

How can I send such a request using Alamofire?

I tried this but the result is error with error message `Invalid type in JSON write (NSConcreteData)`
This is my code :

```
    let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
    let base64String = imageData!.base64EncodedDataWithOptions([])
    
    let parameters = [
        "name": "name",
        "description": "desc",
        "photo": base64String
    ]
    
    let credentialData = "\(id):\(secret)".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    let base64Credentials = credentialData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions([])
    let headers = ["Authorization": "Basic \(base64Credentials)"]

    Alamofire.request(.POST, "", parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON, headers: headers).responseJSON { (response) -> Void in
        print(response)
    }
```

And I followed this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32088875)

If there is another way to do please advice, thanks.

Comment: try using base64EncodedStringWithOptions instead of base64EncodedDataWithOptions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method I'm using you might find it useful

```
let image : UIImage = image.image!
let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
let base64String = imageData!.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)
```

Comment: Wow, thanks it works. I wanna ask what is the Encoding64CharacterLineLength, can i replace it with an empty array?

Comment: no you can't. it's a method that convert image data to long string that you can append to JSON and send as parameters

Comment: you can create a different array and append base64 string to it and send